# Identifying and then loading/reloading a specific tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller set up on my storyboard, and I have inserted a tableView inside this view controller. I want to do a [self.tableView reloadData].

This is what my viewController.m looks like. My tableView is an IBOutlet called sharedView, hence the names in the methods, but I am doing something wrong as on viewDidLoad when I call configureView, and subsequently `[self.sharedView reloadData];` the data doesn't show up inside the table.

```
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "sharedUsersTable.h"

    @interface DetailViewController ()
    - (void)configureView;
    @end

    @implementation DetailViewController

    #pragma mark - Managing the detail item

    - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
    {
        if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
            _detailItem = newDetailItem;

            // Update the view.
            [self configureView];
        }
    }

    - (void)configureView
    {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.

        if (self.detailItem) {
            self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"lock_name"] description];

            activeUsers = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"active_shared_users"];
            [self.sharedView reloadData];

            //NSLog(@"Info: %@", activeUsers);
        }
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        [self configureView];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSString *)sharedView:(UITableView *)sharedView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return @"Shared with";
    }

    - (NSInteger)sharedView:(UITableView *)sharedView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return activeUsers.count;
    }

    - (sharedUsersTable *)sharedView:(UITableView *)sharedView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"sharedUser";


        sharedUsersTable *cell = [sharedView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[sharedUsersTable alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSDictionary *key;
        NSString *name;
        NSString *email;
    //    NSString *permission;

        key = [activeUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        name = [key objectForKey:@"shared_user_name"];
        email = [key objectForKey:@"email"];

        NSLog(@"Info: %@", name);

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email];

        return cell;
    }

    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }


    @end
```

Comment: What's with theses UITableView delegates methods that begin with "shareView" instead of "tableView"?

Comment: Yes, I think I've mixed them up. What exactly have a I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add info about protocols that Your VC is implementing:

```
@interface DetailViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
- (void)configureView;
@end
```

and then:

```
- (void)configureView
    {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.

        if (self.detailItem) {
            self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"lock_name"] description];

            activeUsers = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"active_shared_users"];
            /* I assume that Your table view is self.sharedView though You should change the name and I assume that it is connected to VC */
            self.sharedView.dataSource = self; 
            self.sharedView.delegate = self; 

            [self.sharedView reloadData];

            //NSLog(@"Info: %@", activeUsers);
        }
    }
```

You can also set data source and delegate directly in storyboard - I think that You have to ctrl+drag from table view to vc. Sorry if this is not correct - I do not use IB for quite some time no - only code.

And one more thing - read this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource
And change method names to be exactly the same as in the protocol - If You do not It won't work.

For better undesstanding data sources and delegates try:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using a UIViewController and not UITableViewController. If you are using UIViewController then you will need to implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSourceDelegate. You will also need to connect those delegates either through code or using the interface builder or Storyboard.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?